# Make Account Lock (Laravel 5.7) Auth

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

How to make `Account Locked` and lock the user after `X` minutes of inactivity. And make him/her to write password and re-login. How can I do that? Do I need to do with making new method in `Auth\LoginController` or what? Help.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is already included in Laravel. Have a look at the configuration file `config/session.php`. It contains a configuration key called `lifetime` which is exactly what you are looking for:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Lifetime
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the number of minutes that you wish the session
| to be allowed to remain idle before it expires. If you want them
| to immediately expire on the browser closing, set that option.
|
*/

'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 120),
```

As you can see, the setting can also be set via the environment variable `SESSION_LIFETIME`.

Comment: Are we talking about `x` minutes idle time or `x` minutes after login?

Comment: The first one. `X` minutes idle time

Comment: Then the built-in system should work. If it doesn't, file a bug report in the Laravel github project...